# Copying file from one directory to another and open new document with servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I want to copy file from one directory to another and then I want to open new copied document a new page using servlets. I wrote this code in my servlet to copying file.

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String Docpath=request.getParameter("document");
        String docname=request.getParameter("docName");
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename="+docname);
        ServletOutputStream  outs =  response.getOutputStream ();
        BufferedInputStream bis=null;
        BufferedOutputStream bos=null;
        File file=new File("T:\\Temp\\"+docname);
        try {
            Path original=Paths.get(Docpath);
            Path destination=Paths.get("T:\\Temp\\"+docname);
            Files.copy(original, destination,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            InputStream input=new FileInputStream(file);
            bis=new BufferedInputStream(input);
            bos=new BufferedOutputStream(outs);
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = bis.read(buf)) > 0) {
                bos.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }finally {
            bis.close();
            bos.close();
        }
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

But it gives me this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.solr.openDocumentServlet.doPost(openDocumentServlet.java:74)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I don't know how to fix it. Can you help me please?

Comment: [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/218510/3511123) Which line in your code is line #74?

Comment: @JozefChocholacek I find the problem.The `Docpath` and `docname` are coming `null`. I have another problem, the code opens some `.pdf` correctly but it gives me `failed to load pdf document` error when open some `.pdf` .